# vbscript a condition statement based off of a Membership group In Active directory

Tags: vbscript

I use vbscript to autolaunch internet explorer windows through a client folder in our environment. we just introduced a new system that manages our logons and the autolaunch is based off a computer policy in that system. it can only run off of a specific computer policy. So my idea was to add a conditional statement that said. If one user logs query ad if they are apart of this group launch this window, else launch the windows we have already been launching. I have the code to create and launch websites through vbscipt, what i am looking for is the script to query ad and based on group member ship launch that windows else launch the normal ones. the system is called imprivata.

Comment: the system is called imprivata if that helps

Comment: Would the users always be a direct member of the group, or is indirect possible (i.e. a member of some child group which itself is a member of the group you are concerned with)

Answer (score 0):

This script might do what you want:

```
strGroup = "GroupName"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strDomain = objNetwork.UserDomain
strUser = objNetwork.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomain & "/" & strUser)

Dim found
found = false
For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
    If StrComp(objGroup.Name, strGroup, 1) = 0 Then
         found = true
         Exit For
    End If
Next

' use the found variable to decide what to do
```

Just change `"GroupName` to the group you're looking for.

However, Morbo's comment is important, since if you care about indirect memberships, you'd have to recurse through all the groups found to see if any of them, or the groups they're a member of etc, are a member of the group you care about.